# CakePHP SaveAll filename

Tags: save, cakephp-2.4

When I'm trying to use the `saveAll` function, it's not saving properly when there's an image uploaded to the data.

```
$this->Deal->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Here's an example of data that's working:

```
array(2) {
  ["Resort"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["resort"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["rating"]=>
    string(3) "4.0"
    ["image_link"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["trip_advisor"]=>
    string(12) "123123123123"
    ["image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["deal_id"]=>
    string(3) "258"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "245"
    ["filename"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["type"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["error"]=>
      int(4)
      ["size"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["Deal"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "258"
  }
}
```

Here's an example of data that's not working:

```
array(2) {
  ["Resort"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["resort"]=>
    string(4) "Test"
    ["rating"]=>
    string(3) "4.0"
    ["image_link"]=>
    string(40) "http://google.com"
    ["trip_advisor"]=>
    string(6) "123123"
    ["image"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["deal_id"]=>
    string(3) "258"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "245"
    ["filename"]=>
    array(5) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(12) "logo.png"
      ["type"]=>
      string(9) "image/png"
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpZtCTVC"
      ["error"]=>
      int(0)
      ["size"]=>
      int(3702)
    }
  }
  ["Deal"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "258"
  }
}
```

### Update

It's not only not saving, it's simply returning nothing. I get an empty page when I try the var_dump:

```
var_dump($this->Deal->saveAll($this->request->data));
```

Also, there's no error in the `error_log`.

### Update 2

After digging further, I found out it was an issue of memory limit so I've updated the limit and now I get the error:

```
Can not determine the mimetype.
```

From what I see in the Validation class of CakePHP, it's trying to get the mime type of the `tmp_name` which is `/tmp/phpZtCTVC` and it seems like it can't get it so it's throwing an exception.

Comment: Use debug instead of var_dump in cakephp which will well format your data..And is filenames table configuration all good ?

Comment: @ManoharKhadka Thanks. Take a look at my second update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that the php extension `fileinfo` was not enabled.

Just did a recompile of php with the extension and everything worked fine after that. :)